# click event for a link is not working for phantomjs

Tags: phantomjs, nightwatch.js

I am using nightwatchjs for end to end testing. My test passes for chrome, firefox, ie and edge but one of the test fails for phantomjs. click event for url seems to fail.

```
'do somethings' : function(browser) {
        browser
            .setValue('input[id=SearchInput]', '000')
            .click('button[id=Button]')
            .assert.containsText('label[id=nOutput]', '000')
            .click('a[id=link]')// this click is not working
            .pause(1000)
            .assert.value('input[id=Input]', 'A')
            .assert.value('input[id=InputB]', 'B')

            //reset page
            .click('button[id=__xmlview0--clearButton]')
            .end()
    },
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Do you mean there is no test run happening in phantomjs? Also how did you come to know the url navigation is not happening? as the phantomjs is seemless

Comment: All test runs except one which I mentioned in code. Looks like `.click('a[id=link]')` is not working

Comment: Interesting. Can you post the error that you can see in the console?

Comment: `Testing if value of <input[id=InputA]> equals: "A".  - expected "10" but got: ""` .click() didnt work that why I get this error

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a Selenium issue.

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/5404

Selenium first gets the element's position, then sends a mouse click event. If the element moved between the time, the element will not be clicked.

I've encountered this too, my test case is trying to click A, but B gets clicked. Still trying to figure out a solution.

In another project I also encountered another reason. The page is responsive-ready, some elements are `display:none` when browser width is less than, say, 1000px. When nightwatch launches Chrome or Firefox, the browser window is full screensize, but phantomjs's default viewport size triggers the responsive condition. So Selenium cannot even find the element I want to click.